# JSF: Call javaScript method immediately after view is updated by AJAX call

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In my JSF project I am using Menu component of PrimeFaces to update the center component (center part of the UI page)  of my UI page by the ajax call.

```
<p:menubar>
<p:submenu label="Actions">
    <p:submenu label="Create Privilege">
        <p:menuitem value="Create Administrative Privilege" actionListener="#{leftNavigationBean.selectCenterComponent}" update=":centerPanel">
            <f:attribute name="centerComponentName" value="/CreateAdminPrivilege.xhtml" />
        </p:menuitem>
        <p:menuitem value="Create Access Privilege" actionListener="#{leftNavigationBean.selectCenterComponent}" update=":centerPanel">
            <f:attribute name="centerComponentName" value="/CreateAccessPrivilege.xhtml" />
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

Now after the component get updated by the AJAX call, immediately after that I want to call the JavaScript function to do some operation for my on the updated component.

I have tried calling JavaScript function on the body OnLoad() of the page which is getting update e.g. In Action Menu Action -> Create Privilege -> when CreateAdminPrivilege.xhtml comes in view, on this page body OnLoad() I tried calling JavaScript method but it is not getting called because of the ajax call to this page I guess.

So I need to figure out the way to call JavaScript method of this AJAX call update.
Help me out with this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `p:menuItem`'s `oncomplete` attribute for this:

```html
<p:menuitem ... oncomplete="doSomething()">
```

If you want to further distinguish between success and error of the ajax call, use `onsuccess` or `onerror` attributes:

```html
<p:menuitem ... onsuccess="doSomething()" onerror="doSomethingElse()">
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [jsf js api](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.addOnEvent)

For example:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data){
    if (data.status== 'success') {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```